# How do I handle floating point value inputs for values greater than Float.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, java-6

I have an api which takes a number as a String input and i need to get the Float value of the number. I currently use the Float.ParseFloat method to get the float value of my String number.

According the [java documentation of Float.ParseFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29), it doesn't mention anything about the input being greater than the Float.MAX_VALUE.

One of the ways I was thinking of doing this was by checking the length of the input String is greater than the length of the Float.MAX_VALUE.

Pls suggest how I can go about handling this.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use greater precision. Try double or BigDecimal. There are also arbitrary precision libraries which are open.

  - Here you can find how much each IEEE 754 format can hold: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008 . Float would be near 1.234567*10^38
- If you can't parse it properly (e.g. if there are too many significant digits or the exponent is too big: 1.23456789012345e5000) you won't be able either to hold it in a single precision float.

Comment: `BigDecimal` it is (Javier was too fast xD)

Answer (score 1):

Although the javadoc doesn't make it clear, when I tested it, parseFloat of a String too large simply produced a Float of 'infinity'. You could use the isInfinite() method after creation to check the value.

Using something like BigDecimal would probably be a safer option here, especially if you'll be performing any arithmetic on your value.

Answer (score 0):

The exponent clips to the maximum exponent value. See the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html), line 1197.

Perhaps check for some maximum useful value for your application?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, that's only the first part of the process. See the answers by the people who have actually tried it.

Comment: Ugh. Caught me. No idea where it converts that big honkin' exponent to infinity, but I'm leaving the comment for the sake of the pointer to the source.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is too big the result is set to Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY, as the rules of IEEE FP arithmetic require, and as a 10-second test shows.